# Python 3 number guessing game still says wrong if the answer is right

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ive tried messing around with the code a bit but i cant see the problem, idk if I'm just being blind but there's nothing there.

Originally I had an `if then else` but it wasn't working so I tried making a nested `if` to specify that if it isn't the number, it says wrong.

```
import random


userstart = input("Please type START to play.")

if userstart == "START" or userstart == "start":
    print("Game starting, \n")
    

num1 = random.randint(0, 10)
print(num1)
usernum = input("Guess that number!")
print(usernum)

if num1 == usernum:
    print("Congrats you win!")
    
if num1 != usernum:
    print("WRONG\n")
    print("The number was: ", num1)
```

Comment: Be sure you convert the input to an integer before comparing. The number `5` and the string `"5"` are not equal to each other.

Comment: By the way, this will be a lot more obvious if you get in the habit of printing the `repr()` of your values (by default, `print(x)` acts like `print(str(x))`, not `print(repr(x))`).

Comment: As pointed out, but more specifically, try using `usernum = int(input('Guess that number! '))`.  Note the use of `int()` to convert the input (of type `str`) into an `int` type for matching to the (pseudo-)randomly generated integer.

Answer (score 2):

In python, `input` is a built-in function that returns the user input as a `string`. `randint` on the other hand is a function imported from the standard `random` module which returns an `int`.

So the comparison done in the first if statement,`if num1 == usernum:` results in `False`, as a `str` literal is never equal to an `int` literal.

To solve this issue, you may typecast the input into an `int` using the `int()` constructor:

```
usernum = int(input("Guess the number!"))
```